# Wait() / notify() synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm trying to check how wait/notify works in java.

**Code:**

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
        synchronized (t) {
            try {
                System.out.println("wating for t to complete");
                t.wait();
                System.out.println("wait over");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("entering run method");
        synchronized (this) {
            System.out.println("entering syncronised block");
            notify();
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("leaving syncronized block");
        }
        System.out.println("leaving run method");
    }
}
```

**Output Returned**

```
wating for t to complete
entering run method
entering syncronised block
//sleep called
leaving syncronized block
leaving run method
wait over
```

I was expecting when notify() is executed the wait will be over & `System.out.println("wait over");` will get printed. But it seems it only gets printed when `t` finished its `run()`.

Comment: You're not synchronizing on the same objects

Comment: MyRunnable.this == r != t

Comment: @raul8 Editing question and pasting in the answer makes correct answer invalid. It would be better to add another question.

Comment: I understand that you're studying how `wait`/`notify` work. But anyway I'd strongly recommend you to rather use Java's [high level concurrent API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html) in your code. It's very easy to make hard-to-find mistakes in low-level concurrency code (as you've seen in this example).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Object monitor locks need to be performed a single reference of the same lock...

In your example you are `waiting` on an instance of the `Thread`, but using `notify` from the `Runnable`.  Instead, you should use a single, common lock object...for example

```
public class Tester {

    public static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            try {
                System.out.println("wating for t to complete");
                LOCK.wait();
                System.out.println("wait over");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("entering run method");
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                System.out.println("entering syncronised block");
                LOCK.notify();
                try {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("leaving syncronized block");
            }
            System.out.println("leaving run method");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output...**

```
wating for t to complete
entering run method
entering syncronised block
leaving syncronized block
wait over
leaving run method
```

`wait over` and `leaving run method` could change positions depending on the thread scheduling.

You could try putting the sleep out side the `synchronized` block.  This will release the monitor lock allowing the `wait` section to continue running (as it can't start until the lock is released)

```
    public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("entering run method");
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                System.out.println("entering syncronised block");
                LOCK.notify();
                System.out.println("leaving syncronized block");
            }
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("leaving run method");
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks...but I tried your code .. but it is still not working. Code in question updated

Comment: FYI ``Thread.sleep`` (both forms) is a static method that always puts the calling thread to sleep; thus ``Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000)`` is semantically redundant and probably misleading (e.g. calling ``t.sleep(1000)`` would put the calling thread to sleep, not t).

Answer (score 5):

Answer to updated code :

From [Thread.sleep()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) javadoc:

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the 
>   specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers 
>   and schedulers. **The thread does not lose ownership of any monitors**.

If you call Thread.sleep while inside a synchronized block, other threads won't be able to enter the synchronized block. You should never do time consuming tasks while in a synchronized block to avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

Note (as others pointed out as well) that you have to use the same object for locking/synchronizing in both threads.

If you want your main thread to continue immediately after `notify` is called, you have to relinquish the lock temporarily. Otherwise `wait` will get called only after the secondary thread leaves the `synchronized` block. And it's never a good idea to keep a lock in a long running computation!

One way how to achieve is to use `wait(int)` on the lock instead of `sleep`, because `wait` releases the synchronization lock temporarily:

```
public class Tester {
    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
        t.start();
        synchronized (lock) {
            try {
                System.out.println("wating for t to complete");
                lock.wait();
                System.out.println("wait over");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("entering run method");
            synchronized (lock) {
                System.out.println("entering syncronised block");
                lock.notify();
                try {
                    lock.wait(1000); // relinquish the lock temporarily
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println("got interrupted");
                }
                System.out.println("leaving syncronized block");
            }
            System.out.println("leaving run method");
        }
    }
}
```

However, using these low-level primitives can be very error prone and I'd discourage from using them. Instead, I'd suggest you to use Java's high-level primitives for that. For example, you can use `CountDownLatch` which lets one thread wait until other threads count down to zero:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class TesterC {
    private static final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
        t.start();

        System.out.println("wating for t to complete");
        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("wait over");
    }

    static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("entering run method");
            try {
                latch.countDown();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("got interrupted");
            }
            System.out.println("leaving run method");
        }
    }
}
```

Here you don't have to synchronize anything, the latch does everything for you. There are many other primitives you can use - semaphores, an exchanger, thread-safe queues, etc. Explorer the `java.util.concurrent` package.

Perhaps even better solution is to use even higher level API, such as [Akka](http://akka.io/) provides. There you work with [Actors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) or [Software transactional memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory), which can be composed easily and spare you of most of concurrency issues.